# How add my ip to datebase?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a problem with adding my ip to a database.
I have the following code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$long = ip2long($ip);
if ($polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO post VALUES (NULL, '$long', '$massage', 
'$datum')")){
    $dodano = "Added post to datebase";
}
```

This code is adding strange figure to the table. For example: 520125797
Do you know how to add ip to a database.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php read what this does.

Comment: you need to directly use `$ip` for insertion.  `ip2long()` is doing exactly what it ment for

Comment: simply remove ip2long ; $long = $ip;

Comment: ok now I hava this code:  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; if ($polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO post VALUES (NULL, '$long', '$massage', 
'$datum')"))
                {
                    $dodano = "Added post to datebase";
                } But I have in datebase only figure 310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [ip2long() Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php):-

***ip2long — Converts a string containing an (IPv4) Internet Protocol dotted address into a long integer***

So it is doing correct thing.

You have to use `$ip` directly:-

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ($polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO post VALUES (NULL, '$ip', '$massage', 
'$datum')")){
    $dodano = "Added post to database";
}
```

Note:- As we discussed you need to change your column data-type as `Varchar(256)` rather than `BIGINT`.

Comment: ok I have made this, but in datebase I have only figure 310. I think it should be 31.0.125.101

Comment: Do you know what I should do it now to get in basedate correct ip?

Comment: @user8160814  what is the type of column in which you want to save ip?

Comment: Type of column is BIGINT

Comment: use varchar(256) or varchar(100)

Comment: Wow :D Thank you very much it work :D

Comment: @Paul  glad to help  you :):)

Comment: Storing IPV4 addresses as dotted quads is a bit silly - you can't do do any transformation on the data. Storing it in its native format is a lot more flexible. I'd also recommend using using the databases INET_ATON() / INET_NTOA() rather than PHP's ip2long / long2ip which has some complications on 32 bit machines.